# Windows, monitor a process

Tags: windows

I have searched but no luck,

I am looking for a software or something that will allow me to "Attach it" to a process and listen to what program's that application is calling externally, I need to trace what a particular software i have is running in the background.

Does anyone know of something?

kind regards,

Answer (score 0):

This feature might be in Sysinternals. Lot of IT admins and security professionals use it.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb545021.aspx